# angular 2 set form value and render html component inside reactive form

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bind-html

So I have a `<textarea>` inside a form:

### html

```
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <textarea   formControlName="content" [rows]="5"><textarea>
```

and I am setting the value of content inside the form.

### typescript

```
  this.formGroup.setValue(
        {
          'submitterTolist':  this.result.submitterlist,
          'reviewerTolist':   this.result.reviewerlist,
          'attesterTolist':   this.result.attesterlist,
          'mailCclist':       this.result.email_cc,
          'strsubject':       this.result.subject,
          'content':          this.result.content
        }
```

The issue I am facing is that the content value is `html` which I need to render in the `<textarea>` element, instead of just showing the text as `html`.

Below is an example of the content:

```
<p>Kindly be  informed that the resubmission of Monthly Actuals data for Mexico Internal Fraud Others for Nov 2017 has been approved by the Regional Oversight Manager in the  Enterprise Risk - Fraud Capture Application.</p> <p>The following comments have been provided:</p> Approved. Citirisk Team provided the data to be uploaded. <p>Thank You</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't render html in a text area. You can add a div element and use property biding to set the innerHTML property.

```
<div [innerHTML]="theStringWithHtmlTags"></div>
```

Comment: but than i can't use formcontrol and other stuff i can do with it

Comment: What do you need to do with it?

Comment: perform validations